# iOS - UIScroll on Keyboard popup to textfield on when textfield is inside subview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, delegates, uitextfield

I used code to make the screen scroll when the keyboard is covering up a textfield.

I have a list of textfields, and i started putting each inside of its own uiview for styling and organizational purposes.

now my code only works when i begin actually typing in the textfield.  this is the monstrosity I copied from apple.  Note: I added one parameter to
registerForKeyboardNotifications so that I could include this in a parent class and call it from anywhere

```
  // Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications:(UIScrollView *)scroll
{
    _scroller = scroll;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"hey");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, _activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [_scroller setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    _activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    _activeField = nil;
}
```

I have narrowed down the problem to this part in the viewcontroller

```
    for (id subView in _tpnScroll.subviews)
{

    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        UIView *thisView = subView;
        for(id textfield in thisView.subviews){
            if([textfield isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
                [textfield setDelegate:self];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the original code was

```
    for (id subView in _tpnScroll.subviews){
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [subView setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

in the first example.  im looping through my UIViews, and locating the UITextfields, and setting the delegate to self (this part I don't totally understand, still trying to understand the concept of a delegate)

in the second example, the textfields are located directly on the scrollview so i just loop through them directly.

sorry if this was wordy.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing keyboardWasShown with this.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"hey");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scroller.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // the scroll view will only scroll if the text field is not fully visible
    // no need to check if it is actually covered
    [_scroller scrollRectToVisible:[_scroller convertRect:_activeField.bounds fromView:_activeField]
                        animated:YES];
}
```

Converting the text field's bounds to the scroll view's coordinate system makes sure that it works if the text field is inside the scroll view even if it is not directly inside it.

Comment: this didnt work.  I'm not sure you understand the structure I have.  I have a view -> scrollview -> many views -> many text fields

this was working fine when it was view -> scrollview -> text fields

Comment: @hamobi I understood the structure. The problem with your original code is that you get the frames of the text fields in the views that contain them not in the coordinates of the scroll view.
Where are you setting the content size? Also, make sure the textFieldDidBeginEditing: is being called.

Comment: that method is being called

i notice that this value _activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height
ends up as a negative number.  what could be the cause of this.  How could i get the coordinates of the textfield relative to the scrollview and not the uiview its sitting in?

Comment: I ended up getting tired of banging my head against the wall and used this instead

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: glad you found a solution. In the code I posted, [_scroller convertRect:_activeField.bounds fromView:_activeField] is the part that calculates the textfield's coordinates in the scroll view.